# Why can't I connect my menu to my view controller IBAction?

Tags: xcode, cocoa, nsstoryboard

I have a *document based* application. I have just created menu items in the storyboard and IBActions in my view controller. However the usual way I connect an action to a target doesn't work

```
-(IBAction) markAsHidden:(id)sender;
-(IBAction) markAsVisible:(id)sender;
-(IBAction) toggleHidden:(id)sender;
```

Here is what I see when from my menu item I press Ctrl and mouse click from menu to View Controller. It does not show my IBActions.

Any idea ? My 2 cents guess is that it has to do with the app being document based but... not really sure

[image: connection menu]

Comment: However you're making the connection, Xcode thinks you want to use the action to go to a different controller.  Can you select your menu item and then connect it using a drag from its connections editor (right side screen panel)?

Comment: @PhillipMills I tried that too (from Sent Actions -> selector) to View Controller but same result

Comment: @Thomas Do your IBActions appear in the HUD if you connect to the application scene's First Responder? Connecting to the application scene's First Responder allowed me to connect menu items to IBActions in my view controllers.

Comment: @MarkSzymczyk you're right, it works !!

Comment: @MarkSzymczyk Before I was trying to connect to the View Controller Scene's First Responder with no success. if you wish to make this an answer I will accept it

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Why can't I connect my menu to my view controller IBAction?

Because your menu items and view controller are in different *scenes* in the storyboard. You can think of a scene as an independent graph of objects that are instantiated when the scene is loaded from the storyboard. Objects in different scenes can't be connected together in the storyboard because they're not loaded at the same time.

Just for fun, try creating an instance of your view controller in the *Application Scene* in your storyboard. To do that, you'll probably need to drag a plain old `NSObject` instance into the scene and then set its type. Once you do that, you'll find that you can drag a connection from a menu item to that view controller just as you'd expect, but you can't drag a connection to a different object of the very same type in a different scene.

*Note:* Once you've played around enough to convince yourself that it works, remember to delete the view controller that you added. A view controller without a view is like a duck without a quack, and a view controller and its view hierarchy should be in their own scene.

> My 2 cents guess is that it has to do with the app being document based

No, it doesn't have anything to do with that. You'd have the same problem in an app that's not document-based. You'd also have the same problem if your app were .xib-based instead of using storyboards, since the controller you'd be trying to connect to would be in a completely different .xib file.

The easy solution, as Mark already described, is to use the responder chain. The *First Responder* proxy object is part of every scene, so you can always make connections to it. When you connect a menu item to First Responder its target will be `nil`, which tells `NSMenu` to walk the responder chain until it finds an object that responds to the menu item's action message. It then sends the message to that object.

Comment: Just to be clear, putting an instance of your view controller class in the application scene is interesting to illustrate that the problem is connecting across scenes, **but** it should not be left there. It won't work the way OP wants and will result in confusion due to the stray, not-connected-to-any-view view controller.

Comment: @KenThomases **Right!** I absolutely agree. I only meant to illustrate the issue, not to suggest the OP try to build a real app with a view controller in the application scene. I'll update.

Comment: thanks for the detailed answer. what's the chain of First Responder in a scene ? Application Scene -> View Controller Scene (= our View controller, by default) ?

Comment: Apple has [fully documented the responder chain](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/Devpedia-CocoaApp/Responder.html), so I won't try to do it again in a comment. Just understand that the First Responder in the storyboard editor isn't a single object in your code. It represents whatever object happens to be the first responder, i.e. the first object in the responder chain, at any given moment.

Answer (score 19):

Connect the menu items to the application scene's First Responder. When you connect to the application scene's First Responder, your view controller's IBActions should appear in the HUD's list of available actions instead of the action segues shown in your screenshot's HUD.

Comment: I didn't accept because in the meantime there was another answer more detailed (sorry) so I upvoted you to compensate that

Comment: @MartinDelille Check the connections. Another thing to check in your code is the names of your actions. If there's a misspelling, the menu may be disabled. I had a problem recently where a menu was disabled because I was missing a colon at the end of the action name in my code. If that doesn't help, ask a new question.

Answer (score 2):

If you are converting a project from objective C to Swift, do not make my mistake. When writing your IBAction write like this:

```
 @IBAction func someAction(_ sender:AnyObject) {
     // this will work
 }
```

**Do not omit the underscore before `sender`** or the Interface Builder won't be able to connect to your action as in here:

```
 @IBAction func someAction(sender:AnyObject) {
     // this won't work and IB won't connect to this action
     // because sender will be part of the symbol name
 }
```