# How to attach a custom menu to the main view in a OS X desktop app in Swift

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, nsviewcontroller

Given the following GitHub project:

https://github.com/kellyjanderson/swift-custom-menue

How do I link the menu item Custom >> Custom Action, to the function customAction in the ViewController?

Comment: Can you add more details about the code you have written

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can't I connect my menu to my view controller IBAction?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28657058/why-cant-i-connect-my-menu-to-my-view-controller-ibaction)

Comment: Right click and drag.

Comment: @tbodt That only works when dragging to the AppDelegate.

Comment: You need to put `@IBAction` before the action function.

Comment: @tbodt I just tried that and it will not connect to the connector. :-\

Comment: Then I don't know.

Comment: @Willeke Please take a look at my answer, it is similar to what was discussed in the issue you linked to, but that question never produced the concrete steps to answer my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define an outlet of your menu item in `AppDelegate`

```
@IBOutlet weak var customMenuItem: NSMenuItem!
```

In your view controller first get the instance of `AppDelegate`:

```
 let appDelegate = NSApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
```

Get the instance of the menu item and then bind an `IBAction` to it:

```
appDelegate.customMenuItem.action = #selector(customAction(_:))
```

For e.g., you want to bind an action `customAction` to your menu item. You can add the following code in `viewDidLoad`

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
         let appDelegate = NSApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
         print(appDelegate.customMenuItem)
        appDelegate.customMenuItem.action = #selector(customAction(_:))
    }
```

And then define the `IBAction`

```
 func customAction(sender: NSMenuItem){
        print("Custom Menu Item clicked")
    }
```

Output:

```
<NSMenuItem: 0x6080000a0720 Custom Action>
Custom Menu Item clicked
```

Comment: Thanks for this great answer.

Answer (score 0):

So the linked question [Why can't I connect my menu to my view controller IBAction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28657058/why-cant-i-connect-my-menu-to-my-view-controller-ibaction) came close but did not provide a concrete solution for me. Here is how I solved this.

First in the ViewController you need to mark your function as an @IBAction

```swift
    @IBAction func customAction(sender: NSMenuItem){
        print("Custom Menu Item clicked")
    }
```

Once that function is marked as an IBAction it will be available in the responder chain; so now you can control-click and drag the menu item to the first responder icon and select your function, in this example customAction.